# What should I do about this gsutil "parallel composite upload" warning?

Tags: python, gsutil

I am running a python script and using the `os` library to execute a `gsutil` command, which is typically executed in the command prompt on Windows. I have some file on my local computer and I want to put it into a `Google Bucket` so I do:

import os

```
command = 'gsutil -m cp myfile.csv  gs://my/bucket/myfile.csv'
os.system(command)
```

I get a message like:

> ==> NOTE: You are uploading one or more large file(s), which would run significantly faster if you enable parallel composite uploads. This
>   feature can be enabled by editing the
>   "parallel_composite_upload_threshold" value in your .boto
>   configuration file. However, note that if you do this large files will
>   be uploaded as 'composite objects
>   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects'_, which
>   means that any user who downloads such objects will need to have a
>   compiled crcmod installed (see "gsutil help crcmod"). This is because
>   without a compiled crcmod, computing checksums on composite objects is
>   so slow that gsutil disables downloads of composite objects.

I want to get rid of this message either by hiding it if it's irrelevant od actually doing what it suggests, but I can't find the .boto file. What should I do?

Comment: You've got bigger problems with this code than performance -- if you don't have tight control of your filenames, it also could be used in a security breach (to provide a concrete example, trying to upload a file created with `touch '$(rm -rf ~).csv'` wouldn't go well). Much safer to use `subprocess.Popen` or a derivative without `shell=True`, passing each piece of the command line as a separate list element.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Parallel Composite Uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads) section of the documentation for `gsutil` describes how to resolve this (assuming, as the warning specifies, that this content will be used by clients with the `crcmod` module available):

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp bigfile gs://your-bucket
```

To do this safely from Python would look like:

```
filename='myfile.csv'
gs_bucket='my/bucket'
parallel_threshold='150M' # minimum size for parallel upload; 0 to disable

subprocess.check_call([
  'gsutil',
  '-o', 'GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=%s' % (parallel_threshold,),
  'cp', filename, 'gs://%s/%s' % (gs_bucket, filename)
])
```

Note that here you're explicitly providing argument vector boundaries, and not relying on a shell to do this for you; this prevents a malicious or buggy filename from performing undesired operations.

---

If you don't know that the clients accessing content in this bucket will have the `crcmod` module, consider setting `parallel_threshold='0'` above, which will disable this support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you agree that if the size of `bigfile` is less than 150M then the upload command will still work?

Comment: Yes; it simply won't parallelize in that case.

Comment: If in python, wouldn't it be better to use the python api rather than subprocess -> cli? https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html

Comment: @CosminLehene, sounds like a good reason to add your own answer.

Comment: So you should not use the `-m` flag if you set `GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold`, right?

Comment: Also, from the documentation: A file can be broken into as many as 32 component pieces; until this piece limit is reached, the maximum size of each component piece is determined by the variable "parallel_composite_upload_component_size,"

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to set the configuration that the prompt says inside a file in the `BOTO_PATH`. usually `$HOME/.boto`.

```
[GSUtil]
parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 150M
```

For max speed install the `crcmod` C library